# Powershell - Find the latest Friday

Tags: powershell

How can the following code be modified to identify the latest Friday within the past week (instead of the next one), but with formatting?

`$Date = @(@(0..7) | % {$(Get-Date).AddDays($_)} | ? {$_.DayOfWeek -ieq "Friday"})[0]`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23939203/5651418

Comment: If I understood correctly you just need to add a hyphen: `... % {$(Get-Date).AddDays(-$_)} ...`

Comment: That works, but how can I format the output?

Comment: Format to what ? There is no indication of what sort of output you're expecting in your question

Comment: Can this be incorporated in the same command `-UFormat "%d %m %Y"`

Comment: Your expected output would be `1 7 2022` right ?

Comment: Yes, or the option to use any of the other Get-Date format specifiers -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.2#notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post you linked to offers a [more elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58416301/45375), which you can adapt as follows:

```bash
# Get the most recent Friday relative to the given date,
# which may be that date itself.
$mostRecentFriday = 
  ($date = Get-Date).AddDays((-7 - $date.DayOfWeek + [DayOfWeek]::Friday) % 7)
```

If you want to create a formatted *string* representation of the resulting [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instance (all examples below yield something like `'07 01 2022'`:

- To use [*Unix*-style format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date#notes), use [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date)'s `-UFormat` parameter:

  ```bash
  Get-Date $mostRecentFriday -UFormat '%d %m %Y'
  ```
- To use [.NET's format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), use `Get-Data`'s `-Format` parameter:

  ```bash
  Get-Date $mostRecentFriday -Format 'dd MM yyyy'
  ```

  - Alternatively, pass the format string to the `[datetime]`
    instance's [`.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ToString) method:

    ```bash
    $mostRecentFriday.ToString('dd MM yyyy')
    ```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your expected output would be `1 7 2022`, I would personally use a [`do` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.2) that stops as soon as the [`DayOfWeek` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=net-6.0) of the [`DateTime` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) is `Friday`:

```bash
$date = [datetime]::Now
do {
    $date = $date.AddDays(-1)
} until($date.DayOfWeek -eq [DayOfWeek]::Friday)
$date.ToString("d M yyyy")
```

Comment: Incorporating your ToString code seems to do what I need -- `$Date = @(@(0..7) | % {$(Get-Date).AddDays(-$_)} | ? {$_.DayOfWeek -ieq "Wednesday"})[0].ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that some Get-Date -UFormat specifiers didn't seem to work when attempting to incorporate them into an output string.

Should anyone need to incorporate some rarely needed ones (like 'Week of Year' (%G), 'Day of Year (%j), etc) you could preset needed variables and add them to the output string:

`$DayOfYear = (Get-Date -UFormat %j)`

`$WeekOfYear = (Get-Date -UFormat %V)`

`$Date = @(@(0..7) | % {$(Get-Date).AddDays(-$_)} | ? {$_.DayOfWeek -ieq "Wednesday"})[0].ToString("MM-dd-yyyy|Week $WeekOfYear|'Day' $DayOfYear")`

I imagine someone could incorporate all the code into one Powershell command.

Additional Get-Date -UFormat specifiers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.2#notes

Comment: The `.ToString()` method of a `[datetime]` instance knows nothing about Unix date-time formats; only `Get-Date -UFormat` knows how to interpret them. You can pass a `[datetime]` instance to `Get-Date` to operate on that date instead of the current one.